# Android webView Whatsapp Web loads mobile site

Tags: android

I am trying to display the desktop version of Whatsapp Web https://web.whatsapp.com in my Android app. To make it look like a desktop computer opens the website, I do the following:

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.121 Safari/537.36");
```

This used to work but doesn't work anymore. What else can I add to make it look like a desktop accesses the website so I get the desktop website instead of the mobile website?

Comment: are you loading the url with loadUrl ?

Comment: I do `webView.loadUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com");`

Comment: use the following  -->
Webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)
            Webview.settings.setUseWideViewPort(true)

Comment: hello, thank you for the reply but it's not helping, still being redirected to the mobile site without the qr code